# My Haskell Function crashes on complie

Tags: haskell

I am trying to simulate the taylor polynomial of e^x

```
---Macularian for e^x 
e :: (Num a) => a -> Int -> a
e value precsion = sum $ take precsion [((x^n) / product [1..n]) | x <- value, n <- [0..]]
```

This is my error

> Main.hs@3:73-3:78 Could not deduce (a ~ [a]) from the context (Num a)
>   bound by the type signature for e :: Num a => a -> Int -> a at
>   /home/app/isolation-runner-work/projects/75872/session.207/src/Main.hs:2:6-29
>   a is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for e :: Num a
>   => a -> Int -> a at /home/app/isolation-runner-work/projects/75872/session.207/src/Main.hs:2:6
>   Relevant bindings include value :: a (bound at
>   /home/app/isolation-runner-work/projects/75872/session.207/src/Main.hs:3:3)
>   e :: a -> Int -> a (bound at
>   /home/app/isolation-runner-work/projects/75872/session.207/src/Main.hs:3:1)
>   …

Comment: By the way, this is not a "crash" of the compiler, or of your program. It's just a type error.

Answer (score 5):

This part: `x <- value` means that `value` is a list. If you change it to `let x = value` (or just rename `value` to `x` you will fix that specific compile error:

```
e x precision = take precision [ ...formula involving x and n... | n <- [0..] ]
```

You might then run into another compiler error involving your type signature, so I would comment that out and then have `ghci` tell you what the signature should be using `:type` command.

Comment: Don't generate an infinite list and `take` a finite portion. Use `e x precision = [ ...formula involving x and n... | n <- [0 .. precision - 1] ]` instead.

Comment: Haskell has lazy evaluation so the results are the same.